# simple c program not printing output

Tags: c, console

I have a simple c program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int, int);
int add (int a, int b) {
   return a+b;
}

int main(void) {
  int a, b, c;

  printf("Enter the 1st number ");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  printf("Enter the 2nd number ");
  scanf("%d",&b);
  c = add(a, b);
  printf("The value is %d ", c);
  return (0);
}
```

I am compiling the program with `cc main.c`
and when I am running the program with `./a.out`

I am not getting any output in the console.

Comment: Its running perfectly in my system using gcc

Comment: @FFgTYnh What does this  I after a.out mean?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: It's the English word "I", the start of a new phrase. "I am not getting any output". I realise that it's difficult to recognise it in its correct uppercase form, on a website where people largely write it like "i" instead for no discernible reason.

Comment: Maybe this is duplication but here is an example code which makes reading easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output is buffered for performance reasons. Replace

```
printf("The value is %d ", c);
```

with

```
printf("The value is %d\n", c);
```

or use `fflush(stdout);`.

See [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: It would still flush on program end.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but sometimes the newline character is not enough. I'm running mingw gcc (can't remember the exact version, but it might 4.9.2) and even with a newline character at the end of a string doesn't output it unless fflush(stdout) is called.

P.S. who downvoted? It's a good answer, no?