# printf in C does not giving any output

Tags: c, gcc, printf, buffer, flush

I wrote a code in C to print the id number *(could be combination of both numbers and letters)* of the employee. **The compiler takes the id number as an input but it is printing nothing**. At first, I use 'printf' but it is not working so then I googled to end up with that the output is sometimes buffered for performance reasons in many systems. I got many possible answers in some following threads-

- [simple c program not printing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904797/simple-c-program-not-printing-output)
- [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)
- [printf not printing on console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035075/printf-not-printing-on-console)

However, I tried all of the possibilities (being a beginner, implementation can be wrong), but none worked out for me [given as comments]. I have the code like following. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int* ptr;
    int m;
    char n;
    printf("Id number of employee 1:\n");
    printf("Enter your id number length\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("%d\n", m);
    ptr = (int*) malloc (m *sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter your id number:\n");
    scanf("%s", &n);

    // fflush( stdout );
    // fprintf(stderr, "The id number of emploee 1 is %s", n);
    // setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    // setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    // setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);
    // printf("The id number of employee 1 is %s\n", n);

    printf("The id number of employee 1 is %s", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A single char can't hold multiple letters.

Comment: You have allocated `ptr` but then used a `n` which is a single char. And `ptr` needs to store `char` not `int`.  So it should be `char *ptr = malloc(m); scanf("%s", ptr); printf("%s", ptr);`

Comment: Actually probably should be `malloc(m+1)` if `m` represents the id length. Need one extra byte for the string NUL terminator.

Comment: You don't check that `malloc()` succeeded; you don't check that `scanf()` succeeded.  While they are unlikely to fail, when things go wrong, you need to add the missing error checking to see whether that is causing part of the problem.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for your answers. I can realize my fault that I should use char not int and your answer worked out. One more confusion when I am giving the length, actually it has no effect i.e. if I give m = 5 after that I give more than 5 characters or less than 5 character it prints whole the input. How can I fix it to m value?

Comment: [How to limit scanf function in C to print error when input is too long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886594/how-to-limit-scanf-function-in-c-to-print-error-when-input-is-too-long). Please do searches. People are expected to do basic research and you will often find the answers faster that way too.

Comment: @kaylum thank you for giving the solution and the suggestion also...Definitely I'll do basic researches from next time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was said in the comment section "a single char can't hold a string of letters".
There were other things here to make a better code, e.g. freeing allocated memory.
Here is code example of how it can be done:

```
int main()
{
     char* ptr;
     int m;

     printf("Id number of employee 1:\n");
     printf("Enter your id number length\n");
     scanf("%d", &m);

     ptr = (char*)malloc(m * sizeof(char) + 1);

     if (ptr == NULL) {
         printf("Allocation faild...");
         return 1;
         //you can call main to try again...
     }

     printf("Enter your id number:\n");
     scanf("%s", ptr);

     //scanf is not reliable, you can use a loop to enter all characters 
     //to the char array or validate scanf.
     

     printf("The id number of employee 1 is %s",ptr);
     // dont forget to free the allocated data

     free(ptr);
     
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution which works is (without dynamic memory allocation) -

Change `char n` to `char n[m]` directly, no need for pointers

Another solution that works is (with dynamic memory allocation) -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int m = 5;
    printf("Id number of employee 1:\n");
    printf("Enter your id number length\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    char x[m];
    char *n = x;
    n=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*m);
    printf("Enter your id number:\n");
    scanf("%s", n);
    printf("The id number of employee 1 is %s\n", n);
    free(n);
    return 0;
}
```